# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference on Expandable list

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, expandablelistview

this is my first time asking a problem in StackOverflow, I want to show you my code like here :

SecondFragment class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    listView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expand_list);

    final List<String> listGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    listGroup.add("Menu 1");
    listGroup.add("Menu 2");
    listGroup.add("Menu 3");

    List<Makanan> listItem1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Makanan> listItem2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Makanan> listItem3 = new ArrayList<>();
    listItem1.add(new Makanan("Menu 1", "Ikan", "Telur dan Susu", "Panjang", "Bandung"));
    listItem2.add(new Makanan("Menu 2", "Ikan", "Telur dan Susu", "Panjang", "Bandung"));
    listItem3.add(new Makanan("Menu 3", "Ikan", "Telur dan Susu", "Panjang", "Bandung"));

    final HashMap<String, List<Makanan>> lstItemsGroup = new HashMap<>();
    this.mainPresenter.addList(listGroup.get(0),listItem1);
    this.mainPresenter.addList(listGroup.get(1),listItem2);
    this.mainPresenter.addList(listGroup.get(2),listItem3);

    final ListMakanan listMakanan = new ListMakanan(getActivity(),listGroup,lstItemsGroup);
    listView.setAdapter(listMakanan);

    FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.changePage(3);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

MainPresenter class

```
public class MainPresenter {
protected final HashMap<String , List<Makanan>> makananList;
protected IMainActivity ui;

public MainPresenter(IMainActivity active){
    this.ui = active;
    this.makananList = new HashMap<String, List<Makanan>>();
}
public void addList(String title,  List<Makanan> listMakanan){
    makananList.put(title, listMakanan);
    this.ui.updateList(this.makananList);
    this.ui.resetAddForm();
}
```

}

The problem is, why I can't add/put my hashMap with method addList() in my MainPresenter class?

Can u guys solve this?

Thank you very much.

(The error is shown in the title)

Answer (score 0):

You should never do that. the null point exception cause by makananList is nut initialed in the method of addList. Except you call the method before provide a MainPresenter instance.
like below:
`MainPresenter  mp = new MainPresenter (active) mp.addList(parameters)`